# How to obtain the maximum number of subdirectories in a directory from a C program on Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I know the maximum number of files or directories in a directory, varies depending on the filesystem.

From within a C program on Linux, how to obtain the maximum number of directory files in a directory below the current working directory (or determine there is no maximum other than the size of the universe/computer)?

There is probably some `#define` constant somewhere, or perhaps, some entry in some configuration file, but I can't find either.  Do I have to find out what filesystem is for my current directory, and then use the knowledge of that filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific limit on the number of files or subdirectories within a given directory.  There are limits on the total number of inodes in a file system depending on how the file system was built and (mostly) how much space there is in total in the file system.  Each named object requires an inode (but, thanks to hard links, a single inode can have multiple names).  Thus, the limit is primarily controlled by the space available in the file system.

There are usually limits on how deep a directory hierarchy can be — that's the POSIX constant `{PATH_MAX}` defined (or not) in [`<limits.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html), and the related lower-bounds on the minimum acceptable value for `{PATH_MAX}` — `{_XOPEN_PATH_MAX}` (1024) and `{_POSIX_PATH_MAX}` (256).

You can use the functions [`fpathconf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fpathconf.html) and `pathconf()` to find properties of file systems at run-time.  The related function [`sysconf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sysconf.html) handles other configuration properties.

Comment: oh yes, sorry, thank you, I misread some previous answers.  There may be some "hard" limits like 10^20.  Obviously I don't care about that.  

So, how many subdirectories can I put in a directory in a single level, and not suffer performance issues? I would like, as many as memory will let me.  I want to be able to: add such directories, unlink directories, `cd` to these directories.  That's it.  Obviously I will not be doing `ls`, `find`, or anything like that.

Comment: Choose any convenient limit such as 256, 1024, 4096 — you trade off levels of directory for quicker access within a directory. Many schemes are used. For example, many versions of `terminfo` use a directory `/usr/share/terminfo` with a sub-directory for each starting character in terminal names, and then in the sub-directory, the actual terminal entry. Hence `xterm-256color` is likely in `/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color`. Perl's CPAN system uses a two-level scheme: files distributed by `JOHNL` are found in `<cpan-root>/J/JO/JOHNL`. See also `/usr/share/zoneinfo`, `/usr/share/man`, …

Comment: thank you!  So, can you tell me what will go wrong if I have a directory with , say a million directory files in it (all in the same directory), and I only mkdir such directory files, unlink them and cd to them.

Comment: Nothing goes wrong, per se, but some code scans directories, and may use more memory if there are a million entries rather than a thousand or fewer.  Whether you use such code is more debatable.  Also, if you ever run `ls *` in the directory, the argument list will almost certainly be too big, but it will also take a while to get to the point of finding that out.  So, there is no major problem beyond the issues of managing a million different names.

Comment: thank you!  There is no problem managing - the names are integers, between 0 and, well, so far I have seen around 1/2 million for the upper bound.  I could shift the integers into multiple directory levels, but there is no reason in the algorithms to do that, other than some performance disaster if I have a million entries in one directory.  Thank you Jonathan, I really appreciate, I learn from you.

Comment: I am going to have to tell the users, there is this directory here that's hidden, name starts with a dot - nothing to see there.  Do not under any circumstances go in there and attempt to list something.  Ha ha :)  They will have permissions unfortunately to go in there :)

Comment: I tend to avoid more entries in a directory than will fill a single (large) screen when I run `ls`.  I don't always succeed; my `$HOME/bin` directory has about 900 programs and scripts in it.  However, the rule means I aim for not more than a couple hundred files per directory (3-4 columns in a 110x65 window).  YMMV in this case.  If your working with most of the number up to one million, I'd think about 1000 subdirectories encoding the first three digits (with leading zeros), each containing about 1000 files.  Each directory is still rather large, but more comfortable to me.